# VerifyError Mocking Google Maps GeocodingApi with Powermock

Tags: java, unit-testing, powermock, google-geocoding-api

I'm trying to mock Google Maps GeocodingApi.

I used Powermock to mock its static methods.

When I try to launch my unit tests, I get a java.lang.VerifyError

AbstractServiceTest.java

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PowerMockRunnerDelegate(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({ GeocodingApi.class })
public abstract class AbstractServiceTest {

    // (...)

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {

        GeocodingResult fakeResult = new GeocodingResult();


        fakeResult.geometry = new Geometry();
        fakeResult.geometry.location = new LatLng(1, 1);


        AddressComponent number= new AddressComponent();
        number.longName = "1337";

        AddressComponent street = new AddressComponent();
        street.longName = " street test";

        AddressComponent city = new AddressComponent();
        city.longName = " city test";

        AddressComponent postalCode = new AddressComponent();
        postalCode.longName = " postalCode test";

        AddressComponent country = new AddressComponent();
        country.longName = "country test";



        fakeResult.addressComponents[0] = number;
        fakeResult.addressComponents[1] = street;
        fakeResult.addressComponents[2] = city;
        fakeResult.addressComponents[6] = postalCode;
        fakeResult.addressComponents[5] = country;
        // filling
        fakeResult.addressComponents[3] = null;
        fakeResult.addressComponents[4] = null;

        GeocodingResult[] fakeResults = new GeocodingResult[] { fakeResult };

        PowerMockito.mockStatic(GeocodingApi.class);
        PowerMockito.when(GeocodingApi.geocode(any(GeoApiContext.class), anyString()).await()).thenReturn(fakeResults);
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() {
        PowerMockito.verifyStatic();
    }
}
```

This test gives me that error:

```
java.lang.VerifyError: Bad type on operand stack in aastore
Exception Details:
  Location:
     edu/fst/m2/ipii/carpooling/service/AbstractServiceTest.setUp()V @1040: aastore
  Reason:
    Type 'java/lang/Object' (current frame, stack[0]) is not assignable to reference type
  Current Frame:
    bci: @1040
    flags: { }
    locals: { 'edu/fst/m2/ipii/carpooling/service/AbstractServiceTest', 'com/google/maps/model/GeocodingResult', 'com/google/maps/model/AddressComponent', 'com/google/maps/model/AddressComponent', 'com/google/maps/model/AddressComponent', 'com/google/maps/model/AddressComponent', 'com/google/maps/model/AddressComponent', top, top, 'java/lang/Object' }
stack: { 'java/lang/Object', integer, 'com/google/maps/model/AddressComponent' }
  Bytecode:
    (...)
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2658)
at java.lang.Class.getConstructors(Class.java:1638)
at org.junit.runners.model.TestClass.<init>(TestClass.java:39)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.<init>(ParentRunner.java:75)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.<init>(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.<init>(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:110)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:408)
at org.powermock.reflect.internal.WhiteboxImpl.createInstance(WhiteboxImpl.java:1428)
at org.powermock.reflect.internal.WhiteboxImpl.invokeConstructor(WhiteboxImpl.java:1301)
at org.powermock.reflect.Whitebox.invokeConstructor(Whitebox.java:497)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.DelegatingPowerMockRunner$1.call(DelegatingPowerMockRunner.java:96)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.DelegatingPowerMockRunner$1.call(DelegatingPowerMockRunner.java:93)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.DelegatingPowerMockRunner.withContextClassLoader(DelegatingPowerMockRunner.java:127)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.DelegatingPowerMockRunner.createDelegate(DelegatingPowerMockRunner.java:92)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.DelegatingPowerMockRunner.<init>(DelegatingPowerMockRunner.java:60)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:408)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.createDelegatorFromClassloader(JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:156)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.createDelegatorFromClassloader(JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:40)
at org.powermock.tests.utils.impl.AbstractTestSuiteChunkerImpl.createTestDelegators(AbstractTestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:244)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.<init>(JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:61)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.<init>(AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.java:32)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner.<init>(PowerMockRunner.java:34)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:408)
at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.buildRunner(AnnotatedBuilder.java:29)
at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.runnerForClass(AnnotatedBuilder.java:21)
at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
at org.junit.internal.builders.AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.runnerForClass(AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:26)
at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
at org.junit.internal.requests.ClassRequest.getRunner(ClassRequest.java:26)
at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:41)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:212)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:68)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:140)
```

There's not that much help on the web, and I don't know how to solve this error since I can't modify the GeocodingApi class.

Comment: do you have any updates on this? I'm in the same situation as you..

Comment: same with me .. running with intellij but failing with gradle build :(